# How to configure Entity Framework many-to-many with bi-directional lookup

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I don't know how to properly title this question, so I did my best to come up with a descriptive title.

Basically, I have an Entity Framework entity that looks like the following ...

```
public class LegalDocument
{
    public int ExampleId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<LegalDocument> LegalDocuments { get; set; }
}
```

The `LegalDocument` entity needs to be able to have references to other `LegalDocument`s. In the reverse direction, I need to be able to see what other `LegalDocument`s reference this `LegalDocument`.

So it's like several Entity Framework navigational properties, but I don't know how to specify that one of the properties is for `LegalDocument`s referenced within this `LegalDocument`, versus the other `LegalDocument`s that reference this one.

Any ideas?

Comment: did you create a self refence in your database/codefirst it normally should create the many (collection) and at same time a parent (class), and this should be what you are looking for.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Entity Framework many-to-many self-reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9640000/entity-framework-many-to-many-self-reference)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up being easily doable using the fluent API's `HasMany().WithMany()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can maintain the relationship in code having this method in the `LegalDocument` class.

```
public void RelateDocument(LegalDocument document)
{
    LegalDocuments.Add(document);
    document.LegalDocuments.Add(this);
}
```

Use it to relate documents instead of using `LegalDocuments.Add()` directly.

This way `LegalDocuments` navigation property links to documents that current instance added and documents that added the current instance.