# Change relationship in SQL Management Studio 2014

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2013, entity-framework-6, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I have this conceptual model:

[image]

I generate my entities using EF 6.1.3:

[image]

How can I modify the relationship of the conceptual model to a correct generation?

Explaining..

- Id(Department) -> DeptId(Seller): 
  In Department can't only have a List of Sellers? BossId should represent a instance of Seller, not a List and an instance (as in the diagram). Each seller have only 1 boss.
- BossId(Seller) -> Id(Seller): 
  Entity framework creates a list of Departments in Seller.(It doesn't makes any sense)
- Id(Product) -> SimilarId(Product) [Auto relationship]: 
  How can I make a relationship of (*..*)
     [Many-to-Many]? Product(s) can have 0 or * similarProducts, so should represent a List.

Answer (score 0):

There are two primary items, which I see as:

- Each seller has a Boss who is a seller within the department
- Create link between product and similar products

For Boss of Seller, it sounds like you want a one-to-one relationship from Department to Seller to indicate who is the boss. This [tutorial](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-one-relationship-in-code-first.aspx) may help with that. Your current setup is a one-to-many which is why you have a list of departments in Seller that reflects the many Departments that a Seller is a boss for. This should resolve both the "Id(Department) -> DeptId(Seller)" and "BossId(Seller) -> Id(Seller)" parts of your question.

For Product to Similar Products, you need to create a many-to-many link as is shown in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9640000/entity-framework-many-to-many-self-reference). Keep in mind the comment about weird table and key names referencing [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591620.aspx) to combat it.