# How to do a self referencing (reflexive) relation with many - many?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have these classes:

```
MenuComponent
MenuContainer
```

A MenuContainer can be seen as a menu. A menu has many elements. But a menu can be contained by another menu.

I want to persist this but I'm not getting how would be best:

```
namespace menu_builder_rbac {

    public abstract class MenuComponent {

        [Key]
        public int MenuComponentId { get; set; }

        public string DisplayName { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string HtmlId { get; set; }

        public string HtmlCssClass { get; set; }

        public string Url { get; set; }

        public string IconUrl { get; set; }

        public bool Equals(MenuComponent menuComponent) {
            return (this.MenuComponentId == menuComponent.MenuComponentId) || (this.Name == menuComponent.Name);
        }

    }

    public class MenuContainer : MenuComponent {

        public ICollection<MenuComponent> MenuComponentMenuContainer { get; set; }

    }

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9640000/861716

Answer (score 0):

Menus are esentially trees. Your `MenuComponent` would be the equivalente of a node. Each node can have other `MenuComponent`s as children. I don't really see the necesity of `MenuContainer` unless you want to use it as a top level storage of root `MenuComponent`s.

So your classes would look like:

```
public class MenuContainer
{
     public ICollection<MenuComponent> Menus { get; }
}

public class MenuComponent
{
     ....
     public ICollection<MenuComponent> ChildMenus { get; }
}
```